# A-Frame sound component does not change position

Tags: aframe

I wanted to make a sound come from my right side. So I tried using the A-Frame sound component below:

```
<a-sound src="src: url(Buzz.mp3)" autoplay="true" loop="true" position="-20 0 0"></a-sound>
```

I used the -20 coordinate to make sure the sound would come from my far right side. However, no matter how/where I positioned the sound it never changed the perception of where the sound was coming from. Am I using the  component correctly? Here is the entire body:

```
    <body>
<a-scene sound="src:morn.wav; loop:false; autoplay:false; volume:.1;">
<a-sound src="src: url(Buzz.mp3)" autoplay="true" loop="true" position="-20 0 0"></a-sound>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues :

1/ To make the sound on **your** right, you need to attach it to you (= your camera) as a child entity.

2/ Your right is the + X axis, so you should use +1 instead of -20.

```html
<body>
  <a-scene sound="src:morn.wav; loop:false; autoplay:false; volume:.1;">
    <a-camera wasd-controls>
        
        <a-sound src="src: url(Buzz.mp3)" autoplay="true" loop="true" position="1 0 0">
        </a-sound>
      
      </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```